# How to read complicated json response in swift?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift

I am receiving json response in the form
first NSDictionary then NSArray(1) then inside NSArray(2) there is some data that I need to use

I am unable to fetch data inside NSArray(2). Please help.

```
{
data =     {
    stores =         (
                    {
            "_id" = "************";
            address = " ";
            background = " ";
            name = " ";
            offers =                 (
                                    {
                    "_id" = 57493f4edfc5338efa2d4524;
                    description = "some description";
                    image = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/unishop-offers/57493f4edfc5338efa2d4524";
                    "store_id" = 57344bd40f7c7c3b1e8b97cf;
                    terms = "some terms and condition";
                },
```

How do I get image and id from offers array?

So far I have used the code mentioned below:=

```
      if let data = dataDict["data"] as? NSDictionary{
                    if let result = data["stores"] as? NSArray{
                        for item in result{
                            print(item)
                            DataDict = [
                                "id"                     :   item["_id"] as! String,
                                "address"                :   item["address"] as! String,
                                "logo"                   :   item["logo"] as! String,
                                "name"                   :   item["name"] as! String,
                                "phone"                  :   item["phone"] as! String,
                                "offers"                 :   item["offers"] as! NSArray
                            ]
                            print(DataDict)
                            storeArray.append(DataDict)
                            tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. Arrays should be marked with '[', not '('.

Comment: it is very much valid, and I am able to extract data from above mentioned response using NSDictionary and NSArray also Array is always marked with "()" then inside response is dictionary which is marked with "{}"

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Sir I have posted my code as an answer

Comment: @RajatAttri offers is an array ... so you need to loop through it and access image and id from there

Comment: @Raphaël What we see here is not the JSON, it's the printed result of NSArray/NSDictionary made from the JSON.

Comment: @EricD Make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This prints all key/value pairs of the inner array

```
 if let data = dataDict["data"] as? [String:AnyObject],
    stores = data["stores"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
    for store in stores {
      if let offers = store["offers"] as?  [[String:String]] {
        for offer in offers {
          print(offer["_id"]!)
          print(offer["description"]!)
          print(offer["image"]!)
          print(offer["store_id"]!)
          print(offer["terms"]!)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```